# Flutter - TextField auto complete suggestions from SQLite

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I am trying to create an autocomplete `TextField`. This one is working when I used the below hardcoded `List`.

```
List<String> suggestions = [
    "Apple", 
    "Actual",
    "Actuary",
    "America",
    "Argentina",
  ];
```

But when I used to get data from SQLite and filter it's not filtering. Not working. The SQLite list also getting the same format as the above one. But it's not calling to `itemFilter` part. Please help. I am new to flutter.

```
static Future<List<String>> selectItems() async {
var db = await _openDB();
final usersData = await db.query("albums");
return usersData.map((Map<String, dynamic> row) {
  return row["albumname"] as String;
}).toList();}


  List<String> itemsList;

  void selectItems() async {
    itemsList =  await DBManager.selectItems();
  }
```

This is text filed Code

```
  Container(
              width: _width * 2,
              height: 50,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: AutoCompleteTextField(
                controller: txtAlbumSuggest,
                suggestions: itemsList,
                clearOnSubmit: false,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontSize: 15),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.5)
                    )
                ),
               itemFilter: (item,query){
               return item.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase());
               },
                itemSorter: (a,b){
                  return a.compareTo(b);
                },
                itemSubmitted: (item){
                  txtAlbumSuggest.text=item;
                },
                itemBuilder: (context,item){
                  return Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          item,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),

                  );

                },
              ), 
            ),
```

Comment: ```void selectItems() async``` rename this method and you may need setstate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this code is within your `DBManager` class:

```
static Future<List<String>> selectItems() async {
 var db = await _openDB();
 final usersData = await db.query("albums");
 return usersData.map((Map<String, dynamic> row) {
   return row["albumname"] as String;
 }).toList();
}
```

You should use `setState()` to update the state of your `Widget` class:

```
  List<String> _itemsList;

  void _loadItems() async {
    setState(() => _itemsList =  await DBManager.selectItems());
  }
```

Otherwise, your `Container` won't get notified of the asynchronous update of the data.

Also, it's important to call `_loadItems()`, in the `Widget` class, immediately after the layout has been loaded, to make sure that the data is fetched:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _loadItems(context));
  }
```

Follows the full example code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: HomeScreen(), title: 'Flutter Example'));
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<String> _itemsList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _loadItems(context));
  }

  void _loadItems() async {
    setState(() => _itemsList = await DBManager.selectItems());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: _width * 2,
          height: 50,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: AutoCompleteTextField(
            controller: txtAlbumSuggest,
            suggestions: _itemsList,
            clearOnSubmit: false,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.5))),
            itemFilter: (item, query) {
              return item.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase());
            },
            itemSorter: (a, b) {
              return a.compareTo(b);
            },
            itemSubmitted: (item) {
              txtAlbumSuggest.text = item;
            },
            itemBuilder: (context, item) {
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      item,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```