# Flutter - auto complete textfield with suggestions from sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, simpleautocompletetextfield

Auto complete textfield with suggestions from sqlite database. Show one of the data from salute database as title and another as subtitle in the listtile of suggestions. I have used the [sqlite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) plugin

Data model

```
class Note {
  int _id;
  String _title;
  String _description;
  var _chatEnabled;
  var _liveEnabled;
  var _recordEnabled;
  var _raiseEnabled;
  var _shareYtEnabled;
  var _kickOutEnabled;
  String _time;
  String _host;

  Note(this._title, this._description, this._time, this._chatEnabled, this._liveEnabled, this._recordEnabled, this._raiseEnabled, this._shareYtEnabled, this._kickOutEnabled, this._host);

  Note.map(dynamic obj) {
    this._id = obj['id'];
    this._title = obj['title'];
    this._description = obj['description'];
    this._time = obj['time'];
    this._chatEnabled = obj['chatEnabled'];
    this._liveEnabled = obj['liveEnabled'];
    this._recordEnabled = obj['recordEnabled'];
    this._raiseEnabled = obj['raiseEnabled'];
    this._shareYtEnabled = obj['shareYtEnabled'];
    this._kickOutEnabled = obj['kickOutEnabled'];
    this._host = obj['host'];
  }

  int get id => _id;
  String get title => _title;
  String get description => _description;
  String get time => _time;
  int get chatEnabled => _chatEnabled;
  int get liveEnabled => _liveEnabled;
  int get recordEnabled => _recordEnabled;
  int get raiseEnabled => _raiseEnabled;
  int get shareYtEnabled => _shareYtEnabled;
  int get kickOutEnabled => _kickOutEnabled;
  String get host => _host;

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (_id != null) {
      map['id'] = _id;
    }
    map['title'] = _title;
    map['description'] = _description;
    map['time'] = _time;
    map['chatEnabled'] = _chatEnabled;
    map['liveEnabled'] = _liveEnabled;
    map['recordEnabled'] = _recordEnabled;
    map['raiseEnabled'] = _raiseEnabled;
    map['shareYtEnabled'] = _shareYtEnabled;
    map['kickOutEnabled'] = _kickOutEnabled;
    map['host'] = _host;

    return map;
  }

  Note.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    this._id = map['id'];
    this._title = map['title'];
    this._description = map['description'];
    this._time = map['time'];
    this._chatEnabled = map['chatEnabled'];
    this._liveEnabled = map['liveEnabled'];
    this._recordEnabled = map['recordEnabled'];
    this._raiseEnabled = map['raiseEnabled'];
    this._shareYtEnabled = map['shareYtEnabled'];
    this._kickOutEnabled = map['kickOutEnabled'];
    this._host = map['host'];
  }
}
```

DB manager

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static final DatabaseHelper _instance = new DatabaseHelper.internal();

  factory DatabaseHelper() => _instance;

  final String tableRecentJ = 'jrecentTable';
  final String columnId = 'id';
  final String columnTitle = 'title';
  final String columnDescription = 'description';
  final String columnTime = 'time';
  final String chatEnabled = 'chatEnabled';
  final String liveEnabled = 'liveEnabled';
  final String recordEnabled = 'recordEnabled';
  final String raiseEnabled = 'raiseEnabled';
  final String shareYtEnabled = 'shareYtEnabled';
  final String kickOutEnabled = 'kickOutEnabled';
  final String host = 'host';

  static Database _db;

  DatabaseHelper.internal();

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDb();

    return _db;
  }

  initDb() async {
    String databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, 'jrecent.db');

//    await deleteDatabase(path); // just for testing

    var db = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return db;
  }

  void _onCreate(Database db, int newVersion) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE $tableRecentJ($columnId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $columnTitle TEXT, $columnDescription TEXT, $columnTime TEXT, $chatEnabled INTEGER, $liveEnabled INTEGER, $recordEnabled INTEGER, $raiseEnabled INTEGER, $shareYtEnabled INTEGER, $kickOutEnabled INTEGER, $host TEXT)');
  }

  Future<int> saveNote(Note note) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var result = await dbClient.insert(tableRecentJ, note.toMap());
//    var result = await dbClient.rawInsert(
//        'INSERT INTO $tableNote ($columnTitle, $columnDescription) VALUES (\'${note.title}\', \'${note.description}\')');

    return result;
  }

  Future<List> getAllNotes() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    var result = await dbClient.query(tableRecentJ, columns: [columnId, columnTitle, columnDescription, columnTime, chatEnabled, liveEnabled, recordEnabled, raiseEnabled, shareYtEnabled, kickOutEnabled, host]);
//    var result = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $tableNote');

    return result.toList();
  }

  Future<int> getCount() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $tableRecentJ'));
  }

  Future<Note> getNote(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> result = await dbClient.query(tableRecentJ,
        columns: [columnId, columnTitle, columnDescription, columnTime, chatEnabled, liveEnabled, recordEnabled, raiseEnabled, shareYtEnabled, kickOutEnabled, host],
        where: '$columnId = ?',
        whereArgs: [id]);
//    var result = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $tableNote WHERE $columnId = $id');

    if (result.length > 0) {
      return new Note.fromMap(result.first);
    }

    return null;
  }

  Future<int> deleteNote(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.delete(tableRecentJ, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
//    return await dbClient.rawDelete('DELETE FROM $tableNote WHERE $columnId = $id');
  }


  Future<int> cleanNote() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.delete(tableRecentJ);
//    return await dbClient.rawDelete('DELETE FROM $tableNote WHERE $columnId = $id');
  }

  Future<int> updateNote(Note note) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return await dbClient.update(tableRecentJ, note.toMap(), where: "$columnId = ?", whereArgs: [note.id]);
//    return await dbClient.rawUpdate(
//        'UPDATE $tableNote SET $columnTitle = \'${note.title}\', $columnDescription = \'${note.description}\' WHERE $columnId = ${note.id}');
  }

  Future close() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return dbClient.close();
  }
}
```

I want to show title and description in the suggestion of the textfield. How get the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your question is not clear.

I am guessing you want to autocomplete view in your textfile

Here is the package that provides the same.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead

Take look at it.

Comment: I know about these packages and how to have a auto complete textfield, what I just want is that the suggestions which are showing that data should be from sqlite data base...instead of a normal list..I want to use list<Note> [in my code]...that list gets data from sqlite...so how to do it?

Comment: @Jagadish Can you please try this
 TextField(
     autofillHints: [],
   );

Comment: ok, I will try but how to get the suggestions from a list that is from SQLite DB? refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65267434/flutter-textfield-auto-complete-suggestions-from-sqlite question and answer I want something similar to this but how to attain this in my code?